# Change in connection string when application is on VMWARE

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, vmware

I have C# front end application and database is stored in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2008 , database is on my pc . The connection string i am using is below.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
    "data source=JahanzaibNiazi;Initial catalog=abc;Integrated security=TRUE");
```

Every thing is working fine , now i transferred my frontend application on VMWARE , but database is still in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2008 on my pc .

Now what changes should i made into connection string or into my program to connect from vmware to Database.

Comment: First of all, your database is in SQL Server, not in SSMS. SSMS is just a tool used to work with SQL Server databases. Second, no changes will be required to the connection string assuming the VMWare environment is set up correctly.

Comment: Change the datasource with the IP address of your pc given that they reside in the same network. Treat virtual machine as a separate computer on your network.

Comment: I guess you should be able to use a sql alias? Same name for both machines, but specific configuration shows what machine to use.

Comment: database is in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO and Application is on the vmware.